# URLOpen error while running selenium cases in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, selenium

I have my selenium setup in Ubuntu and have written my own framework for Python.
I am running into following error whenever I run any test cases using the framework. 
However I could run the same selenium cases successfully without using my framework.

Things I've tried, but dint work:
Reinstalled selenium however it dint help.
Restart the VM (I can connect to the network anyways)

Could anyone advice me on this error ?

```
   ERROR: setUpClass (__main__.AuraAccountCreation)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "../../../tiselenium/core/testcase.py", line 100, in setUpClass
self.driver = browser_mapping[driver](**args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium-2.37.2-py2.7.egg/selenium    /webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 71, in __init__
self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium-2.37.2-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 113, in start_session
'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium-2.37.2-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 162, in execute
 response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium-2.37.2-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 355, in execute
return self._request(url, method=command_info[0], data=data)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium-2.37.2-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 402, in _request
response = opener.open(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
 response = self._open(req, data)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
'_open', req)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1207, in http_open
return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1177, in do_open
raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

Comment: The symptoms you describe strongly suggest that you framework is invoking selenium with incorrect data.